# AWS page just showing Apache Start page and not html file

Tags: html, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm running an apache server on an Amazon EC2 basic linux instance, and I'm trying to get it to just display a simple test html file that I created. The file is in /home/ec2-user/public_html (just for test purposes). I've changed the DocumentRoot and Directory to point to this directory, but the public dns address is still just showing the default Apache start page. What else do I need to do/change to get this to actually display online?

Edit: I've also uncommented the VirtualHost *:80 line, changed the DocumentRoot and ServerName within the VirtualHost tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had forgotten to change some permissions on the test.html file itself and that was causing a holdup.

Comment: For some reason most of the files just had execute permission and not even read permissions

Answer (score 1):

check running instance's security group HTTP rule. ADD rule if not added:
Select HTTP from the Type list, and leave the source as Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0).